# Custom methods on Model Laravel and Vue

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, model, vue.js

I am currently trying to implement a bookmark feature in my laravel project and i am using this design. 
The Bookmark table is a pivot for User and Post table, a many to many relationship

```
  public function BookmarkPost(Request $request,$id)
{
    $book = Auth::guard('api')->user()->bookmarks()->attach($id);

     return response()->json( $book);
}

/**
 * Unfavorite a particular post
 *
 * @param  Post $post
 * @return Response
 */
public function unBookmarkPost(Request $request,$id)
{
    $unbook = Auth::guard('api')->user()->bookmarks()->detach($id);

    return response()->json( $unbook);
}
```

There is the code for the BookmarkController

After defining the relationship in the User Model, I created a method to check if the post has been favorited in my Post model

```
 public function bookmarked()
    {
           return (bool) Bookmark::where('user_id', Auth::guard('web')->id())
                              ->where('job_id', $this->id)
                              ->first();

      }
```

There is the code for the Post Model. This is supposed to check if the post was bookmared.

So i also set up a vue component that takes in two props

```
<bookmark-icon :id="job.id" :bookmarked="job.bookmarked ? true : false "></bookmark-icon>
```

So my major problem now is i am using the bookmark-icon as a child component how would i call the bookmarked() method on the Vue instance, if it were blade it would have been

```
{{$job->bookmarked()}}
```

How do i get that with Vue??

Comment: You can use a `computed` property like `bookmarked() { return this.job.bookmarked ? true: false }`. Then your property would be `:bookmarked="bookmarked"`.

Comment: You are not getting my question here, i am trying to replicate what this {{$job->bookmarked()}} in vue

Comment: What would you achieve using `{{$job->bookmarked()}}`? Just showing `true` or `false`? Conditionally showing the bookmark icon? `{{ bookmarked ? 'true' : 'false' }}` if it's the former and `v-if="bookmarked"` on the `bookmark-icon` component if it's the latter. Your question is not clear as to what the desired outcome should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access eloquent form in vuejs.

But You can use the relationship BEFORE you pass the data to vuejs.

In order to do that you have to eager load it 
(read up on it on the docs if it is new to you, very useful stuff, especially when it comes to performance)
You can read this article "[Importance of eager loading](https://nickescobedo.com/1072/the-importance-of-eager-loading-laravel-relationships) "

This is how you can do it, something like this code below:

```
public function load_display()
    {

        $job = Job::bookmarked()->get();

        return response()->json($job );

    }
```